# Problem with a dipstick

Tags: calculus, applications

> **The problem:**
>
> Some houses are heated by burning oil. The oil is stored in a horizontal elliptical cylinder that is lying underground. To measure the residual volume, one has to use a dipstick that is brought down towards the bottom of the tank. The oil level $h$ is read by the stick to calculate the volume of the oil.
>
> **Questions:**
>
> 1) A certain tank has a circular section with the radius of $0.85$ metres and the length of $5.2$ metres. Decide an expression for the volume of the oil $V (h)$ as a function of the height $h$.
>
> 2) Observe a tank with the length $l$ and the elliptical section where the ellipticals major axis has the length of $2a$ and its eccentricity is $e$. Decide a simplified formula for $V(h)$.

Comment: Tip for future question writing: Questions that begin with a subset of this text: "So I have this problem I've been trying to solve... I haven't gotten it so far... I'm having a really hard time... I have a feeling that it must be pretty simple... <miscellaneous biographical facts>...it's really important I get this for my test tomorrow...<disparaging statements about a prof's mother>...and so I appreciate your help, thanks!" are cumulatively exhuasting to the reader, and so the question is more eye-catching if you leave out that and include your partial work on the problem itself. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Do you at least know what the formula would be for the partially filled tank?

Comment: You just want the area of the circle/ellipse multiplied by the height.

Comment: That is just what I am having a difficult time with. I know that I am going to have to integrate the formula for the circle segment.

Comment: @ferson2020 that would be OK if the tank was vertical, but the tank here is *horizontal*.

Comment: @rschwieb Oh I see, so the cross section would be vertical? I was going to say, didn't seem like a calculus question at first.

Comment: Right, so you want a formula for the height of a circle as a function of the length, integrate it from $0$ to $h$, then multiply this by $2$ (to get the other half of the circle), and finally multiply this by $l$. Make sense?

Comment: Here is a picture regarding the matter:
http://i.imgur.com/jqha50U.png

Comment: @Darren Let me know if you'd like me to improve the setup description in my solution.

Comment: I'm sorry but it is still a bit unclear to me. How do I begin?

Comment: @Darren Added another sentence about what you are aiming for.

Comment: I am unfortunately still not quite clear on how I would find the expression given only radius and length of the circular section.

Comment: So I need the area of the cross section and then I multiply it by the length of the entire tank in order to get the volume of the oil.

So how do I get the area? The formula for a prism or?

Answer (score 1):

Hint for the set-up: Since the tank is basically a prism with an elliptical cross section, all you need to look at is the area of the cross-section that the oil covers. Once this is found, multiply by the length of the tank to get the total volume of oil.

So, your goal is to model the cross-section. You may as well think of the center of the cross section as being on the origin in the $x-y$ plane. The trick I will suggest to you is to think of the negative x-axis as "down" so that the surface of the leveled oil is actually a horizontal line which is distance $h$ above the "bottom" of the tank (which is the left-most extremity of the cross-section.

By symmetry, you just need to find an expression for the area under the circle (and then ellipsis in the second part), above the $x$-axis between the bottom of the tank (say at $x=b$) and the top of the oil level $b+h$, and then double that (to pick up the mirror image area beneath it.

---

Another way to approach the problem is as a two-part function for $V(h)$. You could find a function for the bottom half of the tank, and then integrate to find area below $h$ and above the bottom half. The problem is that this breaks down when $h$ gets to be higher than half of the tank, because the tank begins to curve back in on itself, and your "bottom function" does not include that. So, you would then have another integral to tell you how much volume is between the top  half and the middle, and then just add the (constant) volume of the already filled bottom half.

Comment: It's not strictly necessary to do this "turn" trick to get the oil level to be vertical. You could just leave it horizontal, and instead think of the tank edge as a function of $y$, rather than $x$, and integrate with respect to $y$.

Comment: And I'm presuming that the ellipsis is also "level" and is not slanted or something weird :) that would need a little more work